# How to deserialize JSON in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc

According to Fiddler, the post that I'm passing from JQuery AJAX is :-

```
[
    {
        "name": "Colour",
        "value": ""
    },
    {
        "name": "Name",
        "value": "The Name"
    }
]
```

With my function in the MVC Controller as

```
/* In Model */
public class SearchObj
{
   public string Colour;
   public string Name;
}

/* In Controller */
    [HttpPost]
public JsonResult getadvancedsearch(SearchObj oSearch)
{
```

I can put a break point on getadvanced but the values are null, am I missing something.  I have done another page that work but the Ajax format is different, I thought using

```
JSON.stringify($("#TheForm").serializeArray())
```

is the best way.  The question is why the values on oSearch blank even when the values aren't?

The JQuery is :-

```
$(function () {
    $("#TheForm").submit(function (e) {
    var status = this.value;
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
    type: "Post",
    url: '@("/fetch/getadvancedsearch")',
    dataType: "json",
    data: JSON.stringify($("#TheForm").serializeArray()),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: ....
```

Comment: Show your ajax query if you don't mind

Comment: Array is not a single object...

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON shows an array of multiple objects, and they don't even look like `SearchObj` objects - you have an array of objects with `name` and `value`, and ASP.NET MVC is looking for one object with `Colour` and `Name`.

If you create a class that has the right fields, and update your `getadvancedsearch` to take an array, the binding should work properly. But it looks like you're simply generating the JSON incorrectly.

You probably really want to do this:

```
$("#TheForm").serialize()
```

That should give you JSON in the right format for your current controller code.

Comment: When I do as above, the format is like a querystring rather than JSON format which I'm not bothered which format it is in, just whether it can be accepted by asp.net.

Comment: The query string format should work fine with the ASP.NET MVC binding - is your `oSearch` object populated correctly when you do that? If not, what value does it get, and what does the query string look like?

Comment: All values are null sadly whatever method i use.

Comment: What does the query string look like?

Comment: Colour=B&Name=MiscellaneousUser

Answer (score 1):

The Json you posted maps to a `IEnumable<CorrectedSearchObj>`

where CorrectedSearchObj looks like this

```
public class CorrectedSearchObj 
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
}
```

if you are trying to send a your SearchObj, then the Json is going to look like

```
{ "Color" : "", "Name": "The Name" }
```

Comment: That is indeed the format I want but the Jquery is not creating that format.  When I get that format, C# populates the variables.  In the end, i've gone about building my own JSON querystring.

Answer (score 0):

Try use

```
var searchObject  ={
  Colour : '',
  Name : ''
};

var fields =$("#TheForm").serializeArray();
jQuery.each( fields, function( i, field ) {
    if (field.name ==='Colour'){
    searchObject.Colour = field.value;
    }
    if (field.name ==='Name'){
    searchObject.Name = field.value;
    }
});
```

pass it to data:

```
data:  JSON.stringify(searchObject),
```

then in controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult getadvancedsearch(string json)
{
SearchObj oSearch= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SearchObj >(json);
```

using Newsoft Json library